# Is there a way to get SQL Server capcity constraints dynamically

Tags: sql-server, information-schema

I have some code which creates database tables dynamically, and I want to ensure that people don't try to do things that result in me trying to create a table with more columns than what SQL Server allows.

According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx), the limit for the max number of columns per (nonwide) table is 1024.

However, this can obviously change in the future, so I don't want to hardcode it in my app.

Is there a way to get this value dynamically using a SQL query (e.g. by reading from some system table or proc)?

Comment: Keep in mind, you also want to consider the max byte length of a single record. One row can have a max length of 8,060 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there's nothing built in that is exposed to us.

Your app would need to maintain some sort of configuration table itself.

You can't even try and parse it out of `sys.messages` as it isn't hardcoded into the text for `message_id=1702`.

> CREATE TABLE failed because column '%.*ls' in table '%.*ls' exceeds
>   the maximum of %d columns.

Your app could of course try and dynamically discover the limit by simply trying `CREATE TABLE` statements with ever greater amounts of columns but that is not a serious suggestion.